# How to set the background of an item on ListView both when pressed and after click?

Tags: android, listview

I have met a problem with ListView.
I want to set a special colour to the item on ListView when it's pressed, so I add this attribute to the ListView on XML:

```
android:listSelector="@color/popup_right_bg"
```

And it works very well.
But, I also want the item to keep it's colour after the click action, so I add these code in the getView() method of the adapter:

```
if (position == selectedPosition){
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.popup_right_bg));
    }else{
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.popup_left_bg));
    }
```

Then I meet a problem: After the click action the colour of the item on ListView is kept, but the colour when the item is pressed is missing. That's to say the following code seems useless.

```
android:listSelector="@color/popup_right_bg"
```

Who can help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you please post adapter code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of all of you, my problem is solved now. Thanks to everyone!
The reason is, when I write this code:

```
if (position == selectedPosition){
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.popup_right_bg));
}else{
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.popup_left_bg));
}
```

the "listSelector" written in the xml will be covered by the background of the convertView.
So, I just create two selector:
selector_left_normal:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

<item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/popup_left_bg"/>
```

selector_left_selected:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

<item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/popup_right_bg"/>
```

and change to this:

```
if (position == selectedPosition){
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_left_selected);
    }else{
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_left_normal);
    }
```

When pressed, the background of convertView will be transparent, so the "listSelector" below it becomes visible.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
                android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
```

add this line in your listview in xml

and make selector like this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_background_normal"></item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have set for it for my adapter so am pasting code ..so you may get reference

```
package com.learningperiod.functional;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BlogArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<BlogURLObject> blogArrayList = new ArrayList<BlogURLObject>();
BlogURLObject blogObj = new BlogURLObject();
 private int selectedIndex;

Context mContext;

 private int selectedColor = Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b");


public BlogArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        ArrayList<BlogURLObject> blogArrayList) {


    this.blogArrayList = blogArrayList;
    this.mContext = context ;
    selectedIndex = -1;
}

public void setSelectedIndex(int ind)
{
    selectedIndex = ind;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int positionInt = position;

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    View view = convertView;
    blogObj = new BlogURLObject();
    blogObj = blogArrayList.get(positionInt);


    if (view == null) {

          viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

         viewHolder.blogNameTextView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.blogNameTextView);

         viewHolder.layoutCell = (LinearLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.layout_cell);


        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
    {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }


    String blogObjString = blogObj.getTitle();

    if(selectedIndex!= -1 && position == selectedIndex)
    {
        viewHolder.layoutCell.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.pressed_color));
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder.layoutCell.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.default_color));
    }

    viewHolder.blogNameTextView.setText(blogObjString);

    return view;
}


class ViewHolder
{
    LinearLayout layoutCell;
    TextView blogNameTextView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return blogArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return blogArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
}
```

and On ListView`s onItemClick event

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        // view.setSelected(true);

        adapter.setSelectedIndex(position); // do not forgot this


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the background to Listview.

If you want to set the background states to list items, set background to adapter layout.
(i.e., For every list you add one adapter. That adapter contains one layout simply one TextView.)

for that Textview set the background as sam said in his answer.